# Mocking library functionality in Scala - access the passed variables and return a desired value?

Tags: scala, unit-testing, mockito

I want to mock an entire library function but having problems mocking a function:

```
import org.mockito.MockitoSugar.mock

object TestRunnerSpec {
  val session = mock[requests.Session]

  val imsExp = "mock-imsExp"
  val clientId = "client-id"
  val clientSecret = "client-secret"
  val token = "jwt-token"
  session.post.apply(s"$imsExp/ims/exchange/jwt/",headers = Map(
    "Content-Type" -> "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
  ),
    params = Map(
      "client_id" -> clientId,
      "client_secret" -> clientSecret,
      "jwt_token" -> token
    )) = {
    // Write Mock Implementation and return a Mock Response
    
    // Access post request params Ex:
    // val headerContentType = headers.get("Content-Type")
    // val clientId = headers.get("Client-id")
    
    // Return the response based on the content type
    

  }
}
```

Can somoene help me implement this method? It would need two things:

1. accessing the mocked variables
2. returning a response accordingly

Comment: What did you try? What's not working?

Comment: The snippet I shared is all I am aware of. I want to override the apply method but I am struggling with the exact syntax I can add

Comment: I'd recommend learning more abot Mockito then. It's also possible that the library you're using for requests offers a native way to write tests.